Какие варианты реализации свёрточных автоэнкодеров существуют?
Я получил в качестве задания найти примеры реализации автоэнкодера, чтобы выбрать среди них лучший, то есть наиболее подходящий для решения основного задания. Изучив варианты из интернета, я нашёл решения в документации Keras, примеры на PyTorch и репозиторий с использование Lasagne. Но в сущности архитектура этих решений не отличается, везде используются только свёрточные слои и слои уменьшения/увеличения размерности изображения. Отсюда и вопрос, скорей всего, существуют некоторые архитектурные решения автоэнкодеров, которые улучшаюи способность модели реконструировать изображения. Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Отвечаю.. больше, горазда больше половины здешних юзеров, не поняли вообще половины слов в тексте.. Просто рекомендую, если хотите получить ответ, оформите текст, чтоб читалось легко и понималось с первого раза) + если задача сложная, разбейте ее на составляющие и спросите не понятное в отдельности) в текущем виде, ваш вопрос улетит в ленте просто без ответа, я уверен на 99.999%) Добавьте конкретики и желаемый результат.. Ваш вопрос специфический, думаете, тут часто спецы с подобным опытом читают ленту..

Ну основную мысль понял .ну или мне кажется что понял .но навыка явно не хватает чтобы точно понять суть. Типо какие существуют автоинкодеры под машиное зрение . Кроме тех что он привел в пример . Я хз какие . не знаю.но думаю вопрос достаточно правильно поставлен .просто нужно малясь отформатировать текст для читабельности.
